# How to get HTTP Response Code to URL with username password?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, http-status-code-401, http-response-codes

I want to get HTTP Response Code of the URL https://example.com/xyz
But to access this URL I have to first pass username password to https://example.com.

I've tried running

```bash
#!/bin/sh
curl -u username:password https://example.com
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "{http_code}" https://example.com/xyz
```

But I am getting `401 Unauthorised Access`.

Comment: There's a space after the colon (`:`) between `username` and `password`.

Comment: No that's a typo here , while running it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Without further information and knowledge about the web page, service, etc. it might not be possible to give a full and/or correct answer. However, since I were running into similar questions in the past I will provide some hints here.

According your very short description I assume that commands like

```bash
curl --silent -u "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" "https://example.com/xyz" --output /dev/null --write-out "{http_code}\n" 
curl --silent "https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@example.com/xyz" --output /dev/null --write-out "{http_code}\n"
```

will **not** not provide the expected result, right?

Depending on the page and service it might be necessary to keep the session alive, store an ID or TOKEN after the login and use it further. I.e. for the service I were using

```bash
curl -u "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}" -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -D - "https://example.com" |  grep "ID=[a-z0-9]*\|TOKEN = '"
```

So I've later "reused" `ID` and `TOKEN` than in a way like

```bash
curl 'https://example.com/xyz'
-H 'Cookie: ID=${ID}'
-H 'Origin: https://example.com'
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'
-H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'
-H 'X-CSRF: ${TOKEN}'
-H 'User-Agent: cURL'
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
-H 'Accept: */*'
-H 'Referer: https://example.com/xyz'
-H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
-H 'Connection: keep-alive
```

and to get the full content of the page.